# Creating a string from a generic list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a string from the values in a list; what I am trying to achieve is the SQL syntax which is used in an update query:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN1 =X WHERE COLUMN2 IN ('A','B','C')
```

(A,B,C are items in my list.) How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
string commaSeparatedList = _list.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x);
```

but it creates the list without the apostrophes.

Comment: If you are building SQL that will be executed be wary of SQL Injection attacks you may be opening your self up to. For example what if a item of your list was called `') or 1=1; --`. I recommend opening a new question with a higher level overview of what you are doing and asking if there is a better method to do what you want to do.

Comment: Another way of solving this in a way that is safer than building a SQL string is using [Linq To Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) to build your query for you. (open a new question if you need help doing Linq to Sql)

Comment: SQL injections don't matter right now,but thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code gives you exactly what you want except for the apostrophes, just stick a

```
.Select(s => "'" + s + "'")
```

between `_list` .and `.Aggregate...`

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [String.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx)  instead:

```
string commaSeparatedList = string.Join(",", _list.Select(s => "'" + s + "'"));
```

Comment: join is way faster than aggregate, have to recommend this.

Comment: So what do you do when one of the members of `_list` contains the value `') or 1=1; --`?

Comment: That's a fair point about `Join`, have an upvote. I just went for "minimal code change".

Answer (score 0):

```
string commaSeparatedList = "'"+_list.Aggregate((a, x) =>  a + "','" + x )+"'";
```